# Sudden CORS violation at localhost/token

Tags: asp.net, networking, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, cross-domain

I've got a solution with two projects. 
- One Web Api (using owin middleware and Oauth for authentication) (located at localhost:2111)
- Frontend app that communicates with the API.  (located at localhost:1634)

Hosted on different local domains to make sure that everything related to cross-origin resource sharing is working.

And everything worked like a charm, when working from home for a couple of months. Now when I am out trevelling and is running the project on other locations I noticed that, for some reason, the CORS handling freaked out. I will try to explain what was happening.

- I run the projects, first the Api and then the frontend.
- I go to the frontend sign in page and trigger a post to the /token endpoint(auth and get a token)
- First error, `http://localhost:2111/token` CORS violation, even though this has never been a problem from home.
- I googled it and found two different "solutions".
- First, add: `context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });` to the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method. **This did not work.**
- Second, add this to your web.config:

`<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>`

Ok, now something actually did happend. The CORS error was replaced by another error message complaining over multiple headers. I figured out that this must be because of `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)` in my Startup.cs file. **I removed it...and was able to sign in again! what a feeling.**. The happiness did not last long...

The price to be able to login is that *ALL* my Api methods are dissallowed, darn. So I restored the code, removed the customHeaders from the web.config and added the app.UseCors() again, (back to normal).

Guess what, now everything works! After doing the above steps I did not get any errors.

But doing this everytime I turn on the computer and launch the project is just not right.
**What is happening here and how do i fix it?**.

Why did this work for months at home but not from other places? It's only localhost developing and testing taking place here...